# Does the primary circuit of a transformer require a load, assuming that the transformer is ideal (No internal resistance of wires etc)

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

Assuming that there is no form of resistance in the primary circuit, and that the secondary circuit contains resistance, will current in the primary circuit be infinite? Will resistance in the secondary circuit provide resistance in the primary circuit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resistance in the secondary will provide resistance in the primary. It’s called the “reflected load”. For an ideal transformer it’s

$$R_{p}=R_{s}\biggl(\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}\biggr)^2$$

For the derivation see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/refload.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal transformer with no load in the secondary circuit acts like a self inductor with the voltage and current $\pi/2$ out of phase with one another.
Hence over a period no energy is gained or lost.

Adding a resistor to the secondary changes things at the primary with the current and voltage now being in phase with one another to to the rest of the circuit connected to the primary the transformer behaves just like a resistor.
Then the power supplied to the primary of the transformer, $V_{\rm P}I_{\rm P}$, will all be dissipated in the resistor, $V_{\rm S}I_{\rm S}$.

Details of this are given in the link provided by @BobD, [Reflected Load in a Transformer](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/refload.html).